# two Objects in same json return

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json, list, wcf

I have Categoreis and Locations

I would like return both in one method.

How can make a use of both Categories.ToList() and Locations.ToList()???

What type of object should I return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that contains both Categories and Locations so you're only returning one object rather than two.